# How to use multiple directories of a variable for PATTERN in install?

Tags: cmake

I created a `GLOBAL` property with the command:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY ADDON_CPYTHON_SOURCES "")
```

With this property, I add an indefinite number of directories through the command:

```
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND_STRING PROPERTY ADDON_CPYTHON_SOURCES "${_exclude_dir};")
```

My intention is to `EXCLUDE` all these directories in the `install` command:

```
  get_property(_exclude_dirs GLOBAL PROPERTY ADDON_CPYTHON_SOURCES)

  install(
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    DESTINATION ${TARGETDIR_VER}
    PATTERN ${_exclude_dirs} EXCLUDE
  )
```

But it doesn't work. For example, if I add these two directories:

```
"addons/example/src; addons/example1/src"
```

The error message is:

```
install DIRECTORY given unknown argument "addons/example1/src".
```

*How can I workaround this problem?*

Comment: Instead of PATTERN use REGEX, it allows to combine multiple searches with `|` operation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I am currently using this solution. But it has a limitation, first you have to init with a dummy value so that the entire directory is not excluded (by ""). I don't like these hacks.

Comment: "you have to init with a dummy value so that the entire directory is not excluded" - If you are about preparing REGEX element by element, then it is not the only possible way to create REGEX. You may still collect parts of REGEX in the list property. And create final regex from the list just before the `install()` command. `list(JOIN)`, `list(TRANSFORM)`,.. - CMake offers many many powerful ways for create something from a list. At least, `foreach()` is always usable for iterate over the list and build anything from its elements.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can add args directly to a list:

```
set(PATTERN_SOURCES_EXCLUDE)

foreach(subdir ${subdir_list})
  list(APPEND PATTERN_SOURCES_EXCLUDE PATTERN "${subdir}" EXCLUDE)
endforeach()

install(
  DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  DESTINATION ${TARGETDIR_VER}
  ${PATTERN_SOURCES_EXCLUDE}
)
```